# Implementing a linked queue with java

Tags: java, queue

I'm having great difficulty coming up with an enqueue method for my queue class. I need it so that the head will toString() into  with it pointing to A first. And the tail to be pointing at C where insertion into the queue will happen. I just need a push in the right direction, thanks!

```
public class SinglyLinkedQueue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SinglyLinkedQueue myQueue = new SinglyLinkedQueue();
        myQueue.enqueue("A");
        myQueue.enqueue("B");
        myQueue.enqueue("C");
        System.out.println(myQueue.toString());
    }
    private SinglyLinkedNode head = new SinglyLinkedNode("",null);
    private SinglyLinkedNode tail = new SinglyLinkedNode("",null);

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return head == null && tail == null;
    }
    public String toString() {
        if(isEmpty() == true) {
            return "";
        } else {
            return toString(head);
        }
    }
    public String toString(SinglyLinkedNode n1) {
        if(n1 == null) {
            return "";
        }
        String comma = "<";
        if(head != n1) {
            comma = ",";
        } if(n1.getNext() == null) {
            comma = ">";
        }
        return comma+n1.getValue()+toString(n1.getNext());
    }
    public void enqueue(String str) {

    }
}
```

Comment: What's your expected/actual results?

Comment: I want the toString() method to return <A,B,C>.

Comment: What is wrong with the linked queue in the JDK?

Comment: Nothing, this is for educational purposes.

Comment: I have an entire stack class implemented and the toString() method works wonderfully. I just copied and pasted it into here because thats what I was told to do.

Comment: what is the output you are getting?

Comment: Using recursion for your toString() will limit the number of element you can have in your queue to the size of your stack.  You should use a loop instead.

Comment: I currently have no output because my enqueue class is empty. I tried doing something similar to a stack which gave me <C,B,A> but thats not my desired outcome.

Comment: In that case, just use the `<` and `>` in the toString(), and append the nodes, you don't need to use recursion.

Comment: @TedBigham What times would I need to iterate past my stack size?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Hmm.. how would i iterate through the for-loop?

Comment: `for(Node n = head; n != tail; n = n.getNext())`

Comment: Ok well it still leaves me with my problem on how to implement enqueue, its very confusing getting the head and tail correct

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a FIFO queue and your `SinglyLinkedNode` constructor is for the node's value and next node: you firstly need set the current tail to point to the new tail, then secondly to set the tail to point to the new tail:

```
    public void enqueue(String str) {
        // Empty queue
        if (isEmpty()) {
            head = new SinglyLinkedNode(str, null);
            tail = head;
        }
        // Non-empty queue
        else {
            SinglyLinkedNode newTail = new SinglyLinkedNode(str, null);
            tail.next = newTail;
            tail = newTail;
        }
    }
```

**Note** that it doesn't make a lot of sense to set the head and tail as separate nodes with an empty String (they are *different* instances of `SinglyLinkedNode`). Instead your declaration of fields in `SinglyLinkedQueue`should be:

```
private SinglyLinkedNode head, tail;
```

Head and tail are just pointers to a particular node(s). You just need to keep them updated as you modify the queue (and of course ensure you keep your nodes all linked appropriately).

Lastly for iterative `toString()` as pointed out by [Ted Bigham](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122279/implementing-a-linked-queue-with-java#comment33562613_22122279):

```
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return "";
        }

        String result = "<";
        SinglyLinkedNode current = head;
        while (current != null) {
            result += current.value;
            current = current.next;

            if (current != null) {
                result += ",";
            }
        }
        return result + ">";
    }
```

Though I think it would be better to return `<>` for empty queue instead as it is more informative and simplifies the code.

Note also the `@Override` annotation should be used as you are overriding the default `toString()` method. Why it is useful is indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why).